# Network problems on my windows 10

Tags: networking, ipv6

I am having trouble connecting with an Informix Database Engine installed on my machine.

When I run a project in Spring Boot I get a Java error saying: "Connection refused". I've been discussing the issue on an IBM forum, and still can't figure it out, but I'm pretty sure it's a network issue.

My computer is called Development, and it has the IP 192.168.100.12 and the Informix listening port is 1526.

If I ping 192.168.100.12, the command runs normally, but if I ping localhost or Development, it returns the IPv6 address: "::1:".

I have the IPv6 protocol box disabled on my network adapter, the Disabled Components key found in the Windows registry under the TCPIP6 --> Parameters key is also set to 0.

The netstat -a command returns the following:
TCP 192.168.100.12:1526 Development:0 LISTENING

I don't understand what is going on, can someone help me?

Comment: Try re-enabling IPv6 (no practical reason for it to be disabled).  Make sure your IP address is DHCP. Then run TCP/IP Reset.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer
  After restarting, test the connection.

Comment: @John Thank you very much, it worked perfectly.

Comment: I posted an answer for you. I trust you will acknowledge.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having trouble connecting with an Informix Database Engine
> installed on my machine.
>
> When I run a project in Spring Boot I get a Java error saying:
> "Connection refused". I've been discussing the issue on an IBM forum,
> and still can't figure it out, but I'm pretty sure it's a network
> issue.

Try re-enabling IPv6 (no practical reason for it to be disabled). Make sure your IP address is DHCP.

Then run TCP/IP Reset.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

(2) ipconfig /flushdns

(3) restart the computer After restarting, test the connection.

Resetting TCP/IP  often works.